# Karma Angular Unit test a promise never being resolved

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, promise, q, resolve

I am trying to ensure my unit test case covers the scenario of a promise never being resolved, and I am having some issues.

A code block is worth a thousand words, so..

```
it('returns my resource', function() {
    var myUser = {name:'Bob'}
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/myresource').respond(200,myUser);
    myService.getMyUser()
    .then(function(data) {
        expect(data).toEqual(myUser);
    },fail);
});
```

This is all well and good, and tests that the response is as expected and also fails the test should the promise be rejected.

However, should the promise never be resolved at all, the test passes and I would like it to fail. I am caching this request in myService like so:

```
var cachedUser;

function getMyUser(forceUpdate) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (cachedUser && !forceUpdate) {
        deferred.resolve(cachedUser);
    } else {
        $http.get('/myresource')
        .then(function(data) {
            cachedUser = data;
            deferred.resolve(data);
        },function(error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        });
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Now in the above scenario, if one were to remove the line "`deferred.resolve(data)`" from within the $http.get, the test would still pass.  This is because the callback function containing the expectation for `data.toEqual(myUser)` is never run.  However the test should fail because removing that line breaks the purpose of this function.

I have tried within the test code to make the positive callback a spy and expect the spy toHaveBeenCalled, but that seems to run before the promise is resolved and fails even though I can see that the spy's function ran via a console log.

I have also tried within the unit test putting the promise in a variable and then `expect(promise.$$state.status).toEqual(1)`, but again it appears that this expectation is run before the promise is resolved and so the test fails when it should pass.

Please be sure you understand the problem before answering, post a comment if I have not been clear.

Comment: Yes, it actually isn't clear enough what the exact question is. There's no  single question mark in the question. Also, the meaning of *Unit test a promise never being resolved* phrase isn't clear as well.

Comment: The question is how to ensure a unit test covers the scenario where .a promise is not ever resolved, which is different than it being rejected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that when dealing with $httpBackend, you must flush() the backend for requests to go through.  I was doing this in an `afterEach()` block around every test, and so when trying to test the state of the promise from within the test block the promise had not actually been resolved yet.

By moving `$httpBackend.flush()` to within the unit test, the promise returned did indeed update its status from 0 to 1.

Here is the final unit test code:

```
it('returns my resource', function() {
    var myUser = {name:'Bob'}
    var promise;
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/myresource').respond(200,myUser);
    promise = myService.getMyUser()
    .then(function(data) {
        expect(data).toEqual(myUser);
    },fail);
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect(promise.$$state.status).toEqual(1);
});
```

Comment: promise.$$state.status assertion is actually isn't necessary. The actual problem is the lack of `$rootScope.$digest()`. This makes `then` part never running. `flush()` does `$digest()` too, and this is why it starts to work. Every $q promise chain should end with `$rootScope.$digest()` in tests. I would recommend to use https://github.com/bvaughn/jasmine-promise-matchers to keep it safe and consistent.